# spawn images with the coordinates of a moving image in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, xcode5, coordinates

I want that bullets (images) can be "fired" from a X-Axis-moving spaceship.

Individual Bullets are with Bullet.center = CGPointMake (Bullet.center.x, Bullet.center.y - 3); 
repeatedly regenerated. 
However, they will, if I have the X-Axis specified indeed spawned , but continue to fly with the x axis of the spaceship on the screen.

what did I do wrong?

-sorry for my english, i am german :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you added the Bullets as Subview / Child of the Spaceship. Try adding them to the spaceship's superview/scene.